# How to optimize a statement of the form "if (A == B) { ...} else if (A < B) {...} else { ....}"

Tags: optimization, premature-optimization

I have a piece of code that's like

```
if (A == B)
{
    ...
}
else if (A < B)
{
    ... 
}
else // (A > B)
{
    ...
}
```

I realize there is a redundancy problem because there will be some of the same bit comparisons going into the computation of `==` and `<`. How can I optimize my code to make it fancier and faster?

Comment: Branch prediction is going to influence how fast this will run much more than minimizing one comparison.

Comment: Other than that - this is really a premature optimization, if you have a logic with 3 different behaviors for `<,>,==` you should use the 3 conditions as you described, makes it readable.

Comment: I think you should change your user name. [Donald Knuth](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) would know the solution :-)

Comment: Some languages might offer a [three way comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_comparison).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For C# you could use a generic function that takes in the 2 values, and then a lambda action for each case.

```C#
void CompareAndAct<T>(T a, T b, Action fnEqualTo, Action fnLessThan, Action fnGreaterThan)  {

   var comparison = System.Collections.Generic.Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(a, b);
   if (comparison == 0) {
      fnEqualTo();
   }
   else if (comparison < 0) {
      fnLessThan();
   }
   else {  //A > B
      fnGreaterThan();
   }
}
```

Then you can re-use it as much as you wanted like so:

```C#
CompareAndAct(a,b, () => Console.Writeline("Equal"),() => Console.WriteLine("Less Than", () => Console.WriteLine("Greater Than"));
```

I can't say I'd recommend doing this, but it'd work.  It's no faster (prob slower), but I suppose one could say that it's "fancier."

Answer (score 1):

You're not specifying the language but depending on language this could be rewritten in many ways

Ruby way (using the [spaceship operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/827649/995714)):

```ruby
case A <=> B
    when -1 then... # A < B
    when  0 then... # A = B
    when  1 then... # A > B
end
```

[Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1370511/995714), [PHP7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30365346/995714) and Groovy also have the same operator. Many other languages have similar operators or functions for the same combined comparison purpose like [`cmp` in Python 2, `compare` in OCaml and `compareTo` in Kotlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_comparison). C# doesn't have that operator but it has the `IComparable` interface with `CompareTo` method.

VB way:

```vb
Select Case A
    Case Is < B
        ...
    Case Is = B
        ...
    Case Is > B
        ...
End Select
```

In C, C++ and many C-like languages without `CompareTo` method you can use this way

```c
int cmp = (A > B) - (A < B);
switch (cmp)
{
    case -1: ...
    case  0: ...
    case  1; ...
}
```

Many languages like Java don't allow you to directly use the comparison results as a numeric value. In that case you can use the [`signum` function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2427159/995714)

```java
switch(Integer.signum(A - B))
```

You can implement `signum` function easily in C and C++ [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1903954/995714)

Those are for the high-level languages. At the assembly level things are simpler. In x86 assembly only a single comparison is needed, then depending on the result we'll jump to the corresponding block, so it's **not** 3 comparisons and the compiler is smart enough to optimize this simple case. For example:

```
    cmp eax, ebx
    je EQUAL_TO      ; jump if =
    ja GREATER_THAN  ; jump if >

    ; less than case's code
    jmp END_CMP

EQUAL_TO:
    ; equal case's code
    jmp END_CMP

GREATER_THAN:
    ; larger than case's code

END_CMP:
```

The same to other architectures with *comparison flags* like ARM or 68k... For architectures without a flag like MIPS you may need one more comparison but never 3 comparisons

MIPS example:

```perl
    beq $t0, $t1, EQUAL_TO       # $t0 = A, $t1 = B; if ($t0 == $t1) equal();
    slt $t0, $t1, $t2            # $t2 = is_less_than = ($t0 < $t1);
    beq $t2, $zero, GREATER_THAN # if (!is_less_than) larger();

    # "less than" code here
    # ...
    j END_CMP

EQUAL_TO:
    # "equal" code
    # ...
    j END_CMP

GREATER_THAN:
    # "larger" code
    # ...

END_CMP:
```

For architectures with *conditional instructions* like ARM or Itanium and with simple enough body in the if-else blocks **you may not even need a jump**

Comment: Good answer for assembly though after having tested for equal and above/greater all that remains is below/less which therefore does not need a test of its own - as per the OP's example. This is what gcc and other compilers would do. In for-debugging generated code you would probably have the two tests performed explicitly, comparison and all. The OP's code might be (somewhat) optimized by testing for the most common/time critical case first and then moving on to less and less common/time critical variants.